# Tableau LOD R Equivalent

Tags: r

I'm using a Tableau Fixed LOD function in a report, and was looking for ways to mimic this functionality in R.

Data set looks like:

```
Soldto<-c("123456","122456","123456","122456","124560","125560")
Shipto<-c("123456","122555","122456","124560","122560","122456")
IssueDate<-as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-01","2017-01-01"))
Method<-c("Ground","Ground","Ground","Air","Ground","Ground")
Delivery<-c("000123","000456","000123","000345","000456","000555")


df1<-data.frame(Soldto,Shipto,IssueDate,Method,Delivery)
```

What I'm looking to do is "For each Sold-to/Ship-to/Method count the number of unique delivery IDs".

The intent is to find the number of unique deliveries that could potentially be "aggregated."

In Tableau that function looks like: 
`{FIXED [Soldto],[Shipto],[IssueDate],[Method],:countd([Delivery])`

Could this be done with `aggregate` or `summarize` as in an example below:

`df.new<-ddply(df,c("Soldto","Shipto","Method"),summarise,
                  Deliveries = n_distinct(Delivery))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy with `dplyr`. You are looking for the number of unique `delivery` for each combination of `soldto`, `shipto` and `method`, which is just `group_by` and then `summarise`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(
  soldto = c("123456","122456","123456","122456","124560","125560"),
  shipto = c("123456","122555","122456","124560","122560","122456"),
  issuedate = as.Date(c("2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-01","2017-01-02","2017-01-01","2017-01-01")),
  method = c("Ground","Ground","Ground","Air","Ground","Ground"),
  delivery = c("000123","000456","000123","000345","000456","000555")
)

tbl %>%
  group_by(soldto, shipto, method) %>%
  summarise(uniques = n_distinct(delivery))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   soldto, shipto [?]
#>   soldto shipto method uniques
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <int>
#> 1 122456 122555 Ground       1
#> 2 122456 124560 Air          1
#> 3 123456 122456 Ground       1
#> 4 123456 123456 Ground       1
#> 5 124560 122560 Ground       1
#> 6 125560 122456 Ground       1
```

Created on 2018-03-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the confirmation. What's the difference in my example vs. yours? Simplicity?

Comment: `ddply` is a function from `plyr`, which is a precursor to `dplyr` as far as I know. I think they do a lot of similar things with different syntax but I use `dplyr` as standard. Here's the [intro](https://blog.rstudio.com/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/) from when `dplyr` was created, note that the `%.%` chain operator is now `%>%`.